# javascript dissapearing object on canvas

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script to draw an image of the sun, and have an image of the earth orbit around it.

I have defined a planet class as so:

```
function planet(name, size, rotateRate, startx, starty, colour, scale, oRad, oAng, oSpd){//container class for planets
this.name = name;
this.rotateRate = rotateRate;
this.x = startx;
this.y = starty;
this.colour = colour;
this.scale = scale;
this.size = size;
this.orbitRadius= oRad;
this.orbitAngle = oAng;
this.orbitSpeed = oSpd;
this.drawByArc = 
    function drawArcCircle(){//draws circles using the arc method
        context.save();
        context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        context.fillStyle = this.colour;
        context.lineWidth=3;
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.x,this.y,this.size*this.scale,0,Math.PI * 2,false)
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
        context.restore();
    }
    }
```

Now I have created two instances of the class in the program and drawn them fine using the following functions:

```
function gameLoop(){//The Game Loop
var thisTime = Date.now();//current time
var deltaTime = thisTime - lastTime;//find difference, not yet used
update();
draw();
lastTime = thisTime;
setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000/60);
}

function draw(){// Draws all the objects
    drawBackground();
    Sun.drawByArc();
    Earth.drawByArc();
}

function update(){// Updates for animation
//var newRotation = this.getCurrantRotation() + (this.getRotationRate()*deltaTime);
var gSegments;
gScale = 4;
simSpeed = 10;
Sun.scale = gScale;
Earth.scale = gScale;
Earth.orbitSpeed = 360/simSpeed;
//Earth.x = Sun.x + Earth.orbitRadius * Math.cos(Earth.orbitAngle * Math.pi / 180);
//Earth.y = Sun.y - Earth.orbitRadius * Math.sin(Earth.orbitAngle * Math.pi / 180);
}
```

When i have the last two lines of the update method commented out, both circles draw fine, however when i add the final two lines in to attempt to update the earths position in orbit, when i attempt to run the code in chrome the Earth sphere vanishes!

Chrome debugger shows no errors so i'm at a loss as to why it occurs.

EDITED::

Well, I found that thanks to a small typing error (math.pi instead of Math.PI) my planet x and y values were becoming NaN.

however now my earth is stuck at at 90 degree point in its orbit and simply doesnt move, at least it draws, any ideas?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint to the draw functions, what are the actual values in Earth.x and Earth.y?

Comment: I'm honestly not even sure how to add a breakpoint in javascript, I've never written anything outside the big comfy IDE that is Visual studio before.

Comment: In both google chrome and firefox you can use the included debuggers to set breakpoints, inspect values while running etc. Highly recommended, helps debugging a lot. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints

Comment: both are apparently at NaN by the time the draw method comes around.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Most of the issues came from using math.pi instead of Math.PI
on top of that, i had not set a value to change the angle of orbit, meaning the orbit always remained at 90, making there be no orbit.

Chrome debug very much helped me in figuring all this out, so thanks a lot user1816548